# Passing JSON data on trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am calling a service that return JSON data.

Script:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/some/service",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {
        if (response.status == "ok" && response.messages.length > 0) {

            // obj is a jQuery object
            obj.trigger(SOME_EVENT, response.messages);

        }
    }
});
```

This is the response example:

```
{
  "status":"ok",
  "messages":[
     {"id":1,"message_text":"latihan"},
     {"id":123,"message_text":"hello"}]
}
```

When obj received the SOME_EVENT trigger, I am expecting it to pass messages data below:

> [{"id":1,"message_text":"latihan"},
> {"id":123,"message_text":"hello"}]

but when I printed messages parameter to console,

```
// on receiving messages
obj.bind(SOME_EVENT, function(sender, messages) {
    console.log(messages);
});
```

turn out, it only passed the last message below:

> {"id":123,"message_text":"hello"}

Can anyone explain why the array of messages is not passed by my custom event?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From http://docs.jquery.com/Events/trigger, the second parameter to the `trigger` function is an array of additional arguments (passed after the event object).

The value of your `response.messages` property is an array, so they are actually passed along to your handler as separate arguments:

```
obj.bind(SOME_EVENT, function(sender, message1, message2/*, etc*/) {
    console.log(message1); // {"id":1,"message_text":"latihan"}
    console.log(message2); // {"id":123,"message_text":"hello"}
});
```

You can collect them cleanly as one array with:

```
obj.bind(SOME_EVENT, function(sender) {
    var messages = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
    console.log(messages); // [{"id":1,"message_text":"latihan"},
                           //  {"id":123,"message_text":"hello"}]
});
```

Answer (score 3):

*crescentfresh* answer is correct and both solutions work and are valid.

Here is a third option for you. You can call the `trigger`-method like this

```
obj.trigger(SOME_EVENT, new Array(response.messages));
```

then `console.log(messages);` will output what you expect

Comment: The shorter array notation will work as well `obj.trigger(SOME_EVENT, [response.messages]);`

Comment: Actually, `console.log(messages[0])` would be needed to output what the OP expects.