# jQuery ajax not returning the whole object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Whenever I do :

```
$.ajax({
  //my settings
}).done(function(data){
  // Publish or store data
});
```

It works perfectly fine! however, I'm trying to apply the observer pattern, because I'm required to, but when I do, using this code:

```
$.ajax({
  // my settings
}).done(function(data){
  $(document).trigger('ALLREADY',data);
});

// Some other part of the code
$(document).on('ALLREADY',function(e,data){
  console.log(data); // WHY?!
});
```

The response (data) is only storing the first value, not the whole array, as it does with the first example, what did i do to break the functionality?

PS: Note that even though it's returning only the first value of a supposedly big array, even when i try to use it, it won't let me, however, i can log it.

Comment: data is a JSON object, and it's not being completely delivered on the second case, it's chopped to just the first value, and i can't even use it, tho i can log it

Comment: something similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639516/passing-json-data-on-trigger

Comment: @Sudhir you solved it thanks my friend

Comment: @SolorzanoJose glad to know it worked for you, i didnt solved it, just showed you the url, btw please try to search before posting, as most problems might have been already answered here.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `data` is an array, each individual piece is sent as a separate argument in the event callback.  It's strange because if `data` were an object this would not be the case (you'd be able to use it like `data`).

Instead, just use `data = arguments.slice(1)`

Comment: I made a typo, it's a JSON object, is it still being sent separately?

Comment: @SolorzanoJose It'd be hard to imagine .. please just give me the exact value of `data` or at least an example so I have something to work with

Comment: Sudhir linked me to the solution, but your first statement was right, it WAS because it was being sent as separate arguments, passing the data parameter as a new array solved it, thanks for your help